# How to organize source code files (.cpp & hpp) in folders

Tags: c++, cascade

I am a java developer and C++ beginner, I want to organize source code files (.cpp & hpp) files in folders, as packages in JAVA

here is my main.cpp

```
// Navigation pane project template
#include "FriendFinderOnBBM.hpp"
#include <bb/cascades/Application>

#include <QLocale>
#include <QTranslator>

using namespace bb::cascades;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // this is where the server is started etc
    Application app(argc, argv);

    // localization support
    QTranslator translator;
    QString locale_string = QLocale().name();
    QString filename = QString( "FriendFinderOnBBM_%1" ).arg( locale_string );
    if (translator.load(filename, "app/native/qm")) {
        app.installTranslator( &translator );
    }

    // create the application pane object to init UI etc.
    new FriendFinderOnBBM(&app);
    // we complete the transaction started in the app constructor and start the client event   loop here
    return Application::exec();
    // when loop is exited the Application deletes the scene which deletes all its children (per   qt rules for children)
}
```

and I put cpp and hpp in to folder called presentation
here is FriendFinderOnBBM.cpp

```
// Navigation pane project template
#include "FriendFinderOnBBM.hpp"

#include <bb/cascades/Application>
#include <bb/cascades/QmlDocument>
#include <bb/cascades/AbstractPane>

using namespace bb::cascades;

FriendFinderOnBBM::FriendFinderOnBBM(bb::cascades::Application *app)
    : QObject(app)
{
    // create scene document from main.qml asset
    // set parent to created document to ensure it exists for the whole application lifetime
    QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("asset:///main.qml").parent(this);

    // create root object for the UI
    AbstractPane *root = qml->createRootObject<AbstractPane>();
    // set created root object as a scene
    app->setScene(root);
}
```

and this is FriendFinderOnBBM.hpp that existing in presentation folder

```
// Navigation pane project template
#ifndef FriendFinderOnBBM_HPP_
#define FriendFinderOnBBM_HPP_

#include <QObject>

namespace bb { namespace cascades { class Application; }}

/*!
 * @brief Application pane object
 *
 *Use this object to create and init app UI, to create context objects, to register the new meta types etc.
 */
class FriendFinderOnBBM : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FriendFinderOnBBM(bb::cascades::Application *app);
    virtual ~FriendFinderOnBBM() {}
};

#endif /* FriendFinderOnBBM_HPP_ */
```

And here is Makefile

```
QMAKE_TARGET  = FriendFinderOnBBM
QMAKE         = $(QNX_HOST)/usr/bin/qmake
TARGET        = $(QMAKE_TARGET)


all: Makefile $(QMAKE_TARGET)

clean:
$(MAKE) -C ./arm -f Makefile distclean
$(MAKE) -C ./x86 -f Makefile distclean


Makefile: FORCE
$(QMAKE) -spec unsupported/blackberry-armv7le-qcc -o arm/Makefile $(QMAKE_TARGET).pro         CONFIG+=device
$(QMAKE) -spec unsupported/blackberry-x86-qcc -o x86/Makefile $(QMAKE_TARGET).pro     CONFIG+=simulator
$(MAKE) -C ./translations -f Makefile update release

FORCE:

$(QMAKE_TARGET): device simulator

device:
$(MAKE) -C ./arm -f Makefile all

Device-Debug: Makefile
$(MAKE) -C ./arm -f Makefile debug

Device-Release: Makefile
$(MAKE) -C ./arm -f Makefile release

simulator:
$(MAKE) -C ./x86 -f Makefile all

Simulator-Debug: Makefile
$(MAKE) -C ./x86 -f Makefile debug
```

**Now My problem:** the compiler can't find the two source code that I put in to folder "presentation"

Thanks

Comment: What does your makefile or build script look like?

Comment: I edited my question and append it, Thanks

Comment: I can't see any reference to the presentation folder in the above code, so I'm not sure how you expect the compiler to guess where those files are. Is the Makefile supposed to trigger some recursive search through certain directories or what?

Comment: then How can I add reference of "presentation" folder in my code?